# Can I use env vars in docker lables?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I dont want to repeat myself, can I do something like this?:

```
ENV VA1=sdfsdf \
    VAR2=dlksjdlfks \
    VAR3=1.2.3

......

LABEL VA1=ENV VA1 \
      VA2=ENV VA2 \
      VA3=ENV VA3 \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should get what you are looking for:

```
ENV VAR1=sdfsdf \
    VAR2=dlksjdlfks \
    VAR3=1.2.3
...
LABEL VA1=$VAR1 \
      VA2=$VAR2 \
      VA3=$VAR3
```